# Is there a way to link an object in the hierarchy to the onclick() method of a panel that I instantiate runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, gameobject

Simplifying, I am creating a **surveyeditor**: in the game, the player must be able to enter n questions and, for each question, 4 different answers.
You can also insert an *image* for each question / answer and that is the problem! The panel where he can declare these informations is a prefab that is instantiated n times, according to the number of questions indicated by the user.
However, the method by which he can insert an image (ie opening a further panel where he can choose the image to instantiate) is present in a Gameobject present in the hierarchy (NOT a prefab).

Currently, it does not seem possible to insert this object in the *onckick ()* function of the button through which the user should choose the image. Is there actually a way?

Comment: how about something like GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Method)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to directly attach the image to the onClick() event. A method that comes to mind (if I understand your use case), would be a listener approach. So once the user clicks the button to attach an image, store that image in a variable. Then another object is checking if this image in this variable is not null. If so, it will grab that image, and attach it to wherever you need it to go, and then set the image variable to null so that it may again listen for more images.